# Angular 6 style not loading properly after first login/navigate

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, sass

As said in the title the css styles don't seem to be loaded correctly. Only after a reload of the page.

At first on login :

[image]

Then after page refresh :

[image]

My app routing :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        component: UnauthenticatedContainerComponent,
        data: { excludeLogin: true },
        children: [
          { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AuthenticatedContainerComponent,
        data: { requireLogin: true },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: RequestContainerComponent,
            children: [
              { path: 'requests/list', component: RequestListComponent },
              { path: 'request', component: RequestComponent },
              { path: 'results/:id', component: RequestResultListComponent, canActivate: [TabGuard] },
            ],
          },
          {
            path: 'maintenance',
            component: MaintenanceComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'settings',
            component: SettingsComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'administration',
            component: AdminComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'train',
            component: TrainComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
];
```

Comment: Any failing CSS requests in your browsers network tab? If no, what response is the request for CSS giving?

Comment: No error in the browser console or in the network.  `what response is the request for CSS giving?` How can I test that ?

Comment: In the browser network tab just look at the HTTP response for the CSS request

Comment: Nothing on first login, on refresh I have roboto `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,700,900`. Edit just removed it completly, same behavior

Comment: ok so its not even making the request for the css on the first login?

Comment: Yes, when the site load on the login page no issue, everything load. But when The user login and there is the `router.navigate('/')` : runtime.js, pollyfills.js, main.js, styles.js, vendor.js ..etc don't load unless I refresh. But what I don't understand is that a big part of the styles are here, like angular material and the component styles. But as in the images above you can nsee that some things are not displayed correctly :/

Answer (score 4):

Ok my bad, I've found the answer :

In my LoginComponent I was using `ViewEncapsulation.NONE`, it was a relica of the previous developers so I removed it and it's working fine now.

see: [Issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16670)